# How to use eloquent to get a value from two Has Many Relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have an issue where a profile can have many campaigns and also many locations.
The campaigns are linked via a pivot table but my goal is just to return all of the location ids.

**Profile:**

```
public function campaigns() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Campaign', 'profile_id', 'id');
}
```

**Campaign:**

```
  public function locations() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Location')->withPivot('campaign_id', 'location_id');
  }
```

Currently I am solving this by doing

```
$campaigns = $profile->campaigns;

[Doing a nested foreach loop and placing each ID into the array]
```

How would I get this via a query?
I've tried

```
 $campaigns = $profile->campaigns()
                        ->with('locations')
                        ->get()
                         ->pluck('location.id');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your goal is to get information from the location, so I'd start your query with that. You can condition your query based on the relationships using the `whereHas()` method.

This assumes your `Location` has the `campaigns` relationship defined, and your `Campaign` has the `profile` relationship defined.

```
$ids = Location::whereHas('campaigns.profile', function ($query) use ($profile) {
    return $query->where('id', $profile->id);
})->pluck('id');
```

You can read more about querying by relationships in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).